# Inserting jQuery references prevents website from working

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I'm editing a website (written by someone else) that works just fine. I wrote a script inside the html code that uses jquery and jquery mobile. I therefore referenced the following scripts in my header:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'>
</script>

<script 
type='text/javascript' src='$root/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js'>
</script>
```

For some reason, the website doesn't load anymore, even though no errors are given by the console. I am not sure why this happens as none of the code in the html file (besides my function) uses jquery.

Any suggestion?

Comment: how do expect the **$root** to be understood in your code?

Comment: It's the root address of my website. Pretty sure it's fine as all my other scripts/stylesheets are referenced like that and it shows up correctly in the source code.

Comment: You mean that in the "View Source" of the page you see the path to the file? Can you post the same markup but from the "View Source"?

Comment: <script 
     type='text/javascript'          
     src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'>
</script><script 
     type='text/javascript'          
     src='http://www.hidden.com/js/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js'>
</script>

I switched my webpage address with "hidden", other than that it's all the same.

Comment: your site throws some JS errors. Failed to load resource http://www.google.com/adsense/domains/caf.js
Failed to load resource http://hidden.com/js/ads.js
Port error: Could not establish connection. Receiving end does not exist. miscellaneous_bindings:236

Comment: @BabakBandpay my website isn't actually called hidden.com. As I mentioned in my comment, I switched the name out for privacy reasons.

Comment: this will be very difficult to find out. I can't guess how the site is initialized. Can you check that?

Comment: @BabakBandpay I just don't understand why those two references can cause this problem as except for one script, none of the code uses jquery. How could these references possibly cause half the webpage to not show up?

Comment: It is not possible for me to say why. This is probably a small issue hidden somewhere in the code.